# lein repl starts in wrong namespace

Tags: clojure, leiningen

**TLDR;**

`lein repl` starts in the namespace defined by `:main` in `project.clj`, instead of `user`, as desired.

**Details**

I have a [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/) project which is deployed as a command-line application in an uberjar, so I can run it like so:

```
java -jar my-app-1.0-standalone.jar --some --args
```

I also have a `dev/user.clj` to give me a nice REPL environment, as [described here](http://dev.solita.fi/2014/03/18/pimp-my-repl.html).

My `project.clj` looks like this:

```clj
(defproject my-app "1.0"
  :main my-app.cli
  :aot [my-app.cli]

  :profiles {:dev {:source-paths ["src" "dev"]}})
```

When I start my REPL, either with `lein repl` from the command line or `M-x cider-jack-in` from Emacs, I am in the `my-app.cli` namespace, rather than `user`.

If I remove `:main my-app.cli` from `project.clj`, my REPL starts in the `user` namespace as I'd expect, but clearly this breaks my uberjar.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When lein repl task runs, it will look up the ns to switch to in this order of preference:

1. ns specified in the :init-ns of the :repl-options
2. ns specified :main
3. user ns

In your case, try adding:

```
:repl-options {:init-ns user}
```

to your project.clj

Comment: Should this still work? I just tried it in Leiningen 2.7.1 under Clojure 1.9.0-beta2, and I'm getting this error: `Could not locate user__init.class or user.clj on classpath`. It does start in the `user` namespace, but there's a big stack trace before it gets there.

Comment: @Ben Kovitz: try creating `src/user.clj`. I can reproduce your error without it, and when I create `user.clj`, I get no error.