# clojure-emacs: cider doesn't start in user namespace

Tags: emacs, clojure, leiningen

Trying to get a few cider things straight today...

When I create a new clojure project with lein new, and then jack into it from my project.clj, the repl is in the clojure.core namespace instead of user.

Obviously I can switch, but it's annoying to do each time. 
I found this answer, [lein repl starts in wrong namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24720367/lein-repl-starts-in-wrong-namespace), but changing :repl-options is having no effect.

Comment: Can't reproduce this in the current 0.8-snapshot. I remember that using `clojure-test-mode` together with `cider` was causing some ns init problems, but nobody has reported any of those in quite a while.

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading. I had this problem with Cider 0.7.0, but after upgrading to Cider 0.8.1 the REPL starts in the user namespace, as expected.